# Creating columns and replacing values based on search result

Tags: python, pandas

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas
import numpy

example_dataset = {
    'Date' : ['01 Mar 2022', '02 Apr 2022', '10 Apr 2022', '15 Apr 2022'],
    'Transaction Type' : ['Contactless payment', 'Payment to', 'Contactless payment', 'Contactless payment'],
    'Description' : ['Tesco Store', 'Dentist', 'Cinema', 'Sainsburys'],
    'Amount' : ['156.00', '55', '21.50', '176.10']
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(example_dataset)

df ['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d %b %Y')
df['Category'] = 'tempvalue'

df['Category'] = numpy.where(df['Description'].str.contains('Tesco|Sainsbury'), 'Groceries', df['Category'])
df['Category'] = numpy.where(df['Description'].str.contains('Dentist|Cinema'), 'Stuff', df['Category'])

print (df)
```

Given the above code I have two related questions please:

1. Is there a better way to create the Category column than with the temp value and later replacing it with specific values as shown?  I ask as it feels messy.
2. How could I have the terms to search for and the category to assign in a separate file?  Is that possible?  I ask as I want to make it easy for myself to add new terms and define the categories in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. First Question**

you don't need to pre-create the new column, you could do something like this:

```
#df['Category'] = 'tempvalue'

df['Category'] = numpy.where(df['Description'].str.contains('Tesco|Sainsbury'), 'Groceries',numpy.nan)
df['Category'] = numpy.where(df['Description'].str.contains('Dentist|Cinema'), 'Stuff',df['Category'])
```

**2. Second Question**

let's create a simple key-value file called `categories.json` in the same directory of your script

```
{
    "Tesco|Sainsbury":"Groceries",
    "Dentist|Cinema":"Stuff"
}
```

you could do something like this to automate the categories assignement

```
import pandas
import numpy
import json

example_dataset = {
    'Date' : ['01 Mar 2022', '02 Apr 2022', '10 Apr 2022', '15 Apr 2022'],
    'Transaction Type' : ['Contactless payment', 'Payment to', 'Contactless payment', 'Contactless payment'],
    'Description' : ['Tesco Store', 'Dentist', 'Cinema', 'Sainsburys'],
    'Amount' : ['156.00', '55', '21.50', '176.10']
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(example_dataset)

df ['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d %b %Y')



with open('categories.json') as file:
    categories_dict = json.load(file)

df['Category'] = numpy.nan
for key,value in categories_dict.items():
    df['Category'] = numpy.where(df['Description'].str.contains(key), value,df['Category'])
```

In this scenario I suggest to mantain the column initialization for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

You could write the search terms in a csv e.g. 'search_terms.csv' like:

```
SearchTerm,Value
Tesco|Sainsbury,Groceries
Dentist|Cinema,Stuff
```

and read it into a dataframe like:

```
df_search = pd.read_csv('search_terms.csv')
```

and build a dictionary like:

```
search_dict = df_search.set_index('SearchTerm')['Value'].to_dict()
```

Now initialize `Category` column to something like:

```
df['Category'] = np.nan
```

and update `Category` in place with `loc` efficiently like:

```
for k in d:
    df.loc[df['Description'].str.match(k),'Category'] = d[k]
```

Output df:

```
    Date        Transaction Type    Description Amount  Category
0   01 Mar 2022 Contactless payment Tesco Store 156.00  Groceries
1   02 Apr 2022 Payment to          Dentist     55      Stuff
2   10 Apr 2022 Contactless payment Cinema      21.50   Stuff
3   15 Apr 2022 Contactless payment Sainsburys  176.10  Groceries
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be faster than Gam's answer, and also, in my opinion, cleaner code:

```
category_dict = {'Groceries':
                     ['Tesco', 'Sainsbury'],
                 'Stuff':
                     ['Dentist', 'Cinema']
                     }
def get_category(description):
    for category, substrings in category_dict.items():
        for substring in substrings:
            if substring in description:
                return category
df['Category'] = df['Description'].apply(get_category)
```

If you want the substrings as the keys, there's this:

```
category_dict ={'Tesco':'Groceries',
                'Sainsbury':'Groceries',
                'Dentist':'Stuff',
                'Cinema':'Stuff'
                     }

def get_category(description):
    for substring in category_dict:
        if substring in description:
            return category_dict[substring]
df['Category'] = df['Description'].apply(get_category)
```